# How to write to a descriptor in Ionic Ble

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, descriptor

I am using the ionic ble library to communicate with a bluetooth device. Currently I am not seeing any function to write to a descriptor. Is this possible with this library?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Maybe writing directly to the descriptor is not needed

Comment: Yes it is. Check [here](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#write) please.

Comment: @Mr.Panda Thank you for your reply. When I click on the link it details how to write to a particular characteristic but not to a descriptor. Is there a way to write to a descriptor?

Comment: I do not think there is any. I only needed notification descriptors until now, to enable notification bit. If that is your case, `ble.startNotification(device_id, service_uuid, characteristic_uuid, success, failure);` does the job.  I might help further if you can explain what exactly you are trying to do?